# Is it possible to have both internal and public API's in Angular libraries

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

How do I structure an Angular library, when I both want to have a public API/SDK and an internal API/SDK.

The public API/SDK is for third party usage.
The internal API/SDK is for internal usage.

So what I want to achieve, is not to expose internal API/SDK for third party, but still be able to use this internal API/SDK inhouse. The reasoning for this is to keep the public API/SDK as simple and clean as possible.

I'm currently using:
angular 9.1.2 but are soon moving to angular 10+
ng-packagr 9.2.1

PS. I'm currently not using bazel.

Comment: How would you distinguish if you are an internal or an external user? The only way to keep things internal is not to publish them.

Comment: Well, this is actually what I'm asking for, a way/mechanism for doing just this. I've seen almost the same question on ng-packagr forum (no solution), so I think the question is relevant.

Comment: And Henry already answered it.